# How To Show Shortcodes In Wordpress Custom Fields?

Tags: functions, customization, custom-field, shortcode

I have created a custom field with pods.io plugin. Now I want to show some tables and buttons using shortcodes in this field. But when I'm putting shortcodes in it, it's showing in normal text. Please tell me how I can use shortcodes in this custom field?

Answer (score 0):

in you template file or anywhere you want to display your shortcode in a custom field use this code

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_field_name_here', true) ); ?>
```

Comment: Where to add this code?

Comment: Theme files where you want it to display @ShibamKar

Comment: Not yet working

Comment: can you paste the code of the file you're posting it in